# Wierd white space between border and content

Tags: html, css

I see whitespace between the div's border and the nav in chrome only at a specific screen size. I also see it in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u13f2xwd/) so I don't have any extra code.
Also same happens in the snippet, I see the white space only when I expand it to full page.

[image: unwanted whitespace]

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
div{
  min-height: 100vh;
  border: 0.5vw solid red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
  background: black;
  height: 11vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <nav>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
border: 0.5vw solid red;
```

and that doesn't give you a whole number as such it anti-alias the border with the white DIV and what you are likely be seeing is more orange than white.

I've come up with a hack by having 2 separate divs one for the nav and that div background is black so your border is anti-alias to black rather than white.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dg45wfc8/

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}
.content-div {
  min-height: calc(((100vh - 11vh) - 0.5vw));
  border: 0.5vw solid red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  border-width: 0 0.5vw 0.5vw 0.5vw;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
}

nav{
  background: black;
  height: 11vh;
}

.nav-div {
 border-width: 0.5vw 0.5vw 0 0.5vw;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: red;
 background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-div">
  <nav>
  </nav>
</div>
<div class="content-div">>
</div>
```

Comment: I knew about anti-aliasing, but I didn't know it happens between things that are next to each other. What exactly is mod and why can't I find anything about it and browser support?

Comment: Oh it is basically modulus? But it is the first time I see it in css?

Comment: But it works when I try it in jsfiddle, but I also don't think it is valid css. How did you come with border-width: mod(0.5vw, 1px) at the first place?

Comment: Yeah, it seems to work in fiddle that why I thought it works but I then tried 10vw and it didn't change the width as expected.

Comment: Yes, same. But I don't think vw is the problem, because web px are not really screen px? So anti-alising is still hapening even without viewport units.

Comment: I've come up with a solution although it is a ugly hack

Comment: I mean I already do translateY and I will just set padding-top the border size, but I guess if another answer doesn't come up adressing a direct fix then I will just accept.

Answer (score 0):

You can add margin-top:-1px to remove the white space coming under the div with border. I used this to fix my white space issue, it works!

```
<div> test </div>

div{
    border: 3px solid #FB982E;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with the unit `vw` you are using in it. When I changed it to the `px` the white gap gets eliminated.

```css
*{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 0px;
  line-height: 0px;
}
.div{
  border: 5px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav{
  background: black;
  height: 11vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="div">
  <nav>
  </nav>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not what I am asking the white space is between the border and the content. I am still seeing it in your example.

Comment: The problem is with the measuring unit you are using.

Comment: No, even after your edit the gap is visible.

Comment: Bro, there is no white space now between the div and nav. It may be possible that you are getting some space below the content due to some chrome extension. Because you have applied the style on `div`. Check the repl here - https://replit.com/@thelovekesh/whitespace#index.html and see the output here - https://whitespace.thelovekesh.repl.co/

Comment: Okay! But I achieve similar results by changing the measurement unit.

Comment: It happens only at certain screen sizes maybe try zoom in and out. Or change the px to another size.

Comment: isn't the output answer to this question?

Comment: Not getting any white space during zoom in and zoom out. Check in the output - https://whitespace.thelovekesh.repl.co/

Comment: I have tried it on many screens with different resolutions. The result is the same.

Comment: @LovekeshKumar  the answer code you posted it has an error you posted the code with ```11vh```  and not ```11px```. just wanted you to notice it..  and maybe @ivaylo copy-pasted the code with error

Comment: @NishantSVispute I added `px` in `border`. See carefully and the edit you suggested was not appropriate as you removed the code snippet in that.